# Mark area of HTML as BRF file

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

The .BRF file format allows for encoding Braille directly (as level 1 or level 2) so that it can be read on a notetaker or embossed for braille readers.  A general website does not need to be encoded as .BRF since screen readers do an effective job of organizing English text.  I'm working on a website that needs to present Music Braille Code (music in braille) and for longer musical scores it is possible to put a link to a BRF file where the user can read the score in a dedicated BRF reader.  But sometimes only a few musical notes in braille need to be displayed on the screen -- is it possible to mark up an area of text as being displayed in BRF code so that it shouldn't be read directly by screen readers?  An ARIA role or something of that sort?

Comment: If delivering text deliberately to braille displays only would help, [the `aria-braillelabel`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-braillelabel) might be interesting? It seems that using the [Unicode Braille Patterns](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#dfn-unicode-braille) come close to what BRF is? Apparently AT should not transform those.

Comment: My users haven't been able to read using Unicode Braille Patterns.  It seems not to be supported in BRF files for most readers for some reason, compared to ASCII text.  I'm surprised, since they've been in use for at least 10 years and they're easily translated.